# How to make a series of calculations in FOR cycle?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have to make a bunch of calculations with only one parameter changing.

For example:

```
Calculation100 = Something100 + SomethingElse100[1] * Other100 / Another100
Calculation110 = Something110 + SomethingElse110[1] * Other110 / Another110
.
.
.
Calculation1120 = Something1120 + SomethingElse1120[1] * Other1120 / Another1120
```

Or the same example in a more conceptual way:

```
for n = 10 to 112 
    Calculation(n*10) = Something(n*10) + SomethingElse(n*10)[1] * Other(n*10) / Another(n*10)
```

How does it work in Pine Script V5, instead of making them manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can put those in an array, you can use a loop.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")

Calculation100 = Something100 + SomethingElse100[1] * Other100 / Another100
var calculation = array.new_float()
var something = array.new_float()
var somethingElse = array.new_float()
var other = array.new_float()
var another = array.new_float()

len = array.size(something)

for i=0 to len-1
    sth = array.get(something, i)
    sthe = array.get(somethingElse, i)
    oth = array.get(other, i)
    anoth = array.get(another, i)
    
    val = sth + sthe * oth / anoth
    
    array.push(calculation, val)

plot(close)
```

Comment: ‍♂️  Perhaps I simplified my code too much, or simply here's the result of the fact that I am not an educated software developer, just a DIY-guy in coding. Because I could not manage to adapt your code into my actual code part. I would show my (~10-line) code for you. Should I make a new question with it?

Comment: I mean, my example code, I simplified too much… Not the actual code. :)

Comment: Yes, I guess a new question is better.

Comment: Dear Vitruvius, it would be sooo useful if (plot) styles and linewidths would accept Series Bool, not just Input Bool variables, like color parameter does. What's the reason behind this difference? What does prevent the engine to make styles and linewidths accept it but makes color parameter able to accept it? May I hope that it can be changed?

We can double the plots etc. but the number of them is limited so we just make ourselves being closer to the wall of the room.

Comment: Why not use a `line`?